# implement restful webservice behind NAT

Tags: c++, web-services, rest, long-polling

As I understand it, it is not simply possible to implement a rest webservice on a device which is behind NAT. So i was searching for some solutions for this.

Is it possible to use `long polling` in order to implement the webservice? this way, the local device will make a call to the remote client (which is exactly what i want), the client has to keep the connection open (keep alive?) until the client want to call a webservice method. It can do so, because the connection is still open. After the call the client will immediately send another poll to the client ... etc.. 
Is it possible to implement it this way?

Another solutions on which i came across:

[ReverseHTTP](http://reversehttp.net/)  - I don't know very much about this, but it sounds like i can implement the webservice with this. right?

There are several other solutions, like TURN or STUN but they seem to be very complicated.

Do you have any suggestions? 
I am using c++/linux on my network devices.

EDIT: Port Forwarding is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of different concepts here in this question.  You can certainly implement a RESTful service behind a firewall/NAT... you just need to configure your firewall/NAT to forward connections to your service.  There are issues of firewall/NAT devices timing out connections... here again, you can configure your device to not do that, or you can update your communication mechanism with some kind of "keep-alive".  "long polling" is somewhat unrelated, and is used as a way of getting an "interactive like response" from a server... basically the server sits on a poll request from a client until it has something to respond with, or the request times out and the client makes another one.  STUN and TURN are more voice/video communications-related technologies.  I suggest starting with simply having your firewall/NAT device forward web-based requests to your web server.

Comment: unfortunately, forwarding ports is not an option :(

Comment: if your *server* is behind a NAT, you need some way for client connections outside of the NAT to get to it.  you really don't have many options here.  forward connections, or make your server have a public address (you can still firewall a public address, just can't NAT without forward).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what transfer protocol you are using, I'm assuming HTTP.

HTTP uses TCP/IP, so your device NAT needs to redirect the connection request to your server.

There's others ways, like if you have more than one internet IP address, so the requests could be directed to the server too, but thats more complicated than port forward so I think its not what you have.

So basically you need to configure the port forward. Take it like a PABX, calls from the exterior lines needs to know a ramal to reach a phone, thats a distant mean to think of it.

And as said, the suggestions you said, are not intended for that, is mainly for client connection, what for many NAT is not necessary, as the NAT is prepared for doing that.

Comment: thanx for the reply, i wish i could simply forward the ports, but thats not an option in my environment.